# C# LINQ Get List subset with difficult condition

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have some `Product` structure, where I have, for example, `ProductId` and `ProductVariantId`. Each of the products can have many variants.
For example, `Product1` can have variant 1 and 2. `Product2` can have variant 1, 2 and 3, so I have list of:

```
ProductId: 1, ProductVariantId 1
ProductId: 1, ProductVariantId 2
ProductId: 2, ProductVariantId 1
ProductId: 2, ProductVariantId 2
ProductId: 2, ProductVariantId 3
```

What I want to do is get for the productId only one given variant. When productId does not have given variant, my mechanism should get take the maximum.

So my example for given variant `3` should looks like:

```
ProductId: 1, ProductVariantId 2 (maximum)
ProductId: 2, ProductVariantId 3
```

I'm trying to do it like:

```
products.ToList().Where(x => x.ProductVariant == givenProductVariant)
```

What I want to add is some kind of database `distinct` on `productId` and getting maximum.

Can I ask for some help, please?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your Product class? You say each product can have many variants, but it sort of seems like each product just has one productid and productvariantid property. So it would be helpful to make sure we understand what you're working with

Comment: A more meaningful sample would also contain a product with `ProductVariantId = 4` which should be excluded if there's another one with `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `GroupBy` approach which orders the groups by a `bool` if the `ProductVariantId = 3` or instead by the `ProductVariantId desc`:

```
int productVariantId = 3;
var query = products.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductVariantId == productVariantId)
                  .ThenByDescending(p => p.ProductVariantId)
                  .First());  // First ensures that we get one row per group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product
        {
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
        }

        static void GetMaxProduct(IList<Product> list,int variant)
        {
            var query = from l in list
                        group l by l.ProductId into g
                        select g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductVariantId == variant) ?? g.OrderBy(x => x.ProductVariantId).Last();
            foreach (Product p in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ProductId:" + p.ProductId + " ProductVariantId:" + p.ProductVariantId);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Product> list = new List<Product>()
            {
                new Product{ ProductId=1, ProductVariantId=1},
                new Product{ ProductId=1, ProductVariantId=2},
                new Product{ ProductId=2, ProductVariantId=1},
                new Product{ ProductId=2, ProductVariantId=2},
                new Product{ ProductId=2, ProductVariantId=3},
            };

            GetMaxProduct(list, 3);
            GetMaxProduct(list, 4);
            GetMaxProduct(list, 1);
        }
```